# How to use acquireTokenSilently in msal

Tags: java, azure-ad-msal

We are trying to migrate from adal to msal using java.
We use [authorization code flow in oauth](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow) to get the refresh token and access token.

**IN ADAL ,we had the following flows:**

1. To get the access token and refresh token we use the auth code flow and follows the following code:

```
ClientCredential credential =
                    new ClientCredential(
                            PRODUCTION_OAUTH_SECRETS.getClientId(), PRODUCTION_OAUTH_SECRETS.getClientSecret());

            AuthenticationContext context =
                    new AuthenticationContext(
                            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + domainName+ "/", true, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future =
                    context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new URI(returnPath), credential, null);
            AuthenticationResult result = future.get();

            OAuth2Token token =
                    new OAuth2Token(
                            result.getAccessToken(), result.getRefreshToken(), result.getAccessTokenType(), null);
```

2. To get a renewed access token we used to use the refresh token in the following way:

```
            AuthenticationContext context =
                    new AuthenticationContext(
                            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + domainName+ "/", true, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future =
                    context.acquireTokenByRefreshToken(credentials.refreshToken, getClientCredential(), null, null);
            AuthenticationResult result = future.get();

            credentials.refreshToken = result.getRefreshToken();
            credentials.accessToken = result.getAccessToken();
            credentials.expiresAt = result.getExpiresOnDate().toInstant();
```

Now we were successfully able to migrate from the above adal code to msal by using the code mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java#adal-to-msal-migration)

And we were also able to create the first access token in msal using the following code:

**IN MSAL, we have the following code:**

1. to get the access token and refresh token we use the auth code flow and follows the following code:

```
            ConfidentialClientApplication app =
                    ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                                    clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret))
                            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + domainName+ "/")
                            .build();

            AuthorizationCodeParameters parameters =
                    AuthorizationCodeParameters.builder(code, returnPath)
                            .scopes(Collections.singleton("offline_access"))
                            .build();

            CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(parameters);
            IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
```

We were successfully able to get the access token and refresh token. But how to get a renewed access token as there is no way to store the refresh token in MSAL.

We tried the following code but it did not work to obtain the access token as the there were no tokens stored in cache.

```
                            ConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(oAuthClientSecret.getClientId(), ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(oAuthClientSecret.getClientSecret()))
                        .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + domainName+ "/")
                        .build();

                // define the scopes to request
                String scopes =  "offline_access";
                // acquire an access token silently
                IAuthenticationResult authResult = cca.acquireTokenSilently(
                        SilentParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(scopes)).build()).join();

                credentials.accessToken = authResult.accessToken();
```

ASK: Can someone be able to explain :

1. How to use the acquireTokenSilently method
2. Are the scopes provide correct?
3. MSAL mentions that the tokens are stored in a [cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java#adal-to-msal-migration). Where is this cache?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your `questions 1 and 3`

> How to use the `acquireTokenSilenty` method

You can implement something like this :

```
    PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(YOUR_CLIENT_ID)
            .authority(YOUR_AUTHORITY)
            .build();
    Consumer<DeviceCode> deviceCodeConsumer = (DeviceCode deviceCode) ->
    // get token for graph
    DeviceCodeFlowParameters parameters =
            DeviceCodeFlowParameters
                    .builder(Collections.singleton("User.Read"), deviceCodeConsumer) 
                    .build();
    IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).join();


    DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(result.accessToken());
    System.out.println(jwt.getAudience().get(0));

    // refresh token
    Set<IAccount> accountsInCache = pca.getAccounts().join();

    IAccount account = accountsInCache.iterator().next();
    // get token for your own api
    SilentParameters silentParameters =
            SilentParameters
                    .builder(Collections.singleton("YOUR_SCOPE"), account)
                    .build();
    result = pca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join();
    jwt = JWT.decode(result.accessToken());
```

> MSAL mentions that the tokens are stored in a cache. Where is this cache?

`MSAL` provides the feature token cache. It caches a `token` after it's been acquired. Then we can try to refresh the `token silently` from the cache with the above method. Please go through below reference links for more details:

Reference links:

[Acquiring tokens silently from cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache)

[Java Core Classes for MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-adal-msal-java#core-classes)